# Is it ok to use Laravel and CodeIgniter side by side?

Tags: codeigniter, laravel

I am total noob to frameworks, I have been doing everything in  raw Php codes only. DB call, authentication, everything using raw phpcodes, but now the time comes for using a phpframework, since I got a new project, its an SMB project, mostly doing administration, reports, lists etc.

I was searching and reading a lot of laravel vs CodeIgniter debates and articles. I still cannot make a full-heated decision to select one. So many says Laravel is awesome, young, powerful, feature-rich etc but on the down side, it is like Ubuntu of PHP? version/update changes too frequent ?

on the side CodeIgniter, so many says its dead but their official announcement confirms the v3 is out and going to v4 steadily.

Since I am new to frameworks and somewhat OOPS also, I think to start using both frameworks sideways for different projects. But my worry is, Will it kill the learning curve ? Is the coding structure of both directly opposite or too far ?

Hope to read some good advises
thanks

Comment: It depends on how good you are at learning things.  We can't advise you.  But ask yourself ... do you need to learn both ... right now?  Don't make things harder for yourself by doing something you don't need to do.

Comment: My two cents about CodeIgniter: isn't dead; and if was, what's the problem? The documentation is all out there and free, you can still develop any application with it. I'm still using CodeIgniter 2.2.0 version and I have no problem with it and I enjoy coding with this framework.

Comment: start with Code-igniter it will decide your future in laravel.

Comment: As @Linesofcode said codeigniter not dead. It is going strong now. codeigniter 3 is out now download here at http://www.codeigniter.com/download and codeigniter 4 coming out in few years time

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of the frameworks on "which is better" value based on general feedback that you may read online. There will always be a camp on each side and people that will love it and those who will hate the software. I personally take a few minutes and literally search for "I left X framework", "I hate X library", "Reasons why I stop using X Y". If the framework/library is popular enough you will most likely will find some people releasing blog posts about it.

My recommendation is to pick one and stick to it, if you have been doing "raw" PHP then almost any framework will come as fresh air since a lot of common tasks will be done for you and if you are experienced you should be able to pick any rather quickly. Sometimes I pick a few frameworks, set a few hours aside and literaly go thorugh their tutorials if they are simple enough to follow. Then try something that I have done before to get a taste of the framework/library in "real-life"

However, I can't not emphasize this enough but **be realistic**. Do not expect one framework to answer all your questions and do every single thing for you, be open to ideas, you may find something in CI that you may port over to Laravel or vice-versa depending on the framework that you select. If you find a catastrophic bug instead of spending hours complaining about it and posting about how terrible the software is on every social channel why not try to solve the issue and contribute to the project that you are using?

In the end the decision is as easy as 1,2,3:
1. Pick one framework/library
2. Stick to it
3. Own the decision